# Microsoft Graph Teams API

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to develop custom team templates using this article: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta"

I am using Microsoft graph (preview online version) to run the sample codes given in the article. When I run the query (after granting permissions and everything), It does create the team however, it only captures the name of the team, non of the other channels or settings and creates it a bunch of time (3 to 4 teams get created) and Microsoft Graph then goes to an empty page.  When I check the history it does give me the "200" return code for success but when I try and open it, it takes me back to an empty page again.

Is there something from the admin center that I need to configure? I understand this is a beta version but I have seen other that were able to run them successfully. I attached pictures to explain further. Thanks for all the help!